# Reconnecting a project to SVN in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a project that has been versioned by SVN for months, but now all of a sudden it seems that Eclipse does not recognize the project as being under version control. In the team menu, I only have Apply Patch... and Share Project...

I tried Share Project as suggested elsewhere, but Eclipse doesn't recognize the project as being under version control.

All the svn dirs exist.

Interestingly, I tried sharing the project to a different repository and I got an error saying that the project was already a working copy for another URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just delete the project on your disk and re-checkout the project from SVN?

Comment: The project on the disk has some newer changes that weren't yet committed (and now can't be committed)

Comment: Tried `svn commit` from command line? If that does not work, check in out in a new directory and use an offline-diff-tool to carry the changes to the newly checked-out one.

Comment: There it is. So obvious, thanks!

Comment: Put this as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few things that you can try.

- If the project is in synch with SVN, probably the easiest way is to delete it and check it out anew.
- Otherwise, you can try to delete the project from your workspace (*not* from disk!) and to re-import it into the workspace.
- If that does not work, you can try to use the SVN command line tools, e.g. `svn commit`, to synchronize your local project with the SVN repository (and check it out anew using Eclipse).
- In case the SVN command line tools do not work, there might to be an actual problem with the SVN files. In this case, you could back up your project (with unsynched changes), check out the project from SVN, and use an offline-diff-tool such as *diff* or *meld* to carry the changes over to the newly checked-out project.

Comment: Right click to Team and Share Project worked great.  Used the default settings and everything synched right back up.

Comment: @ErickRobertson I guess that would be the usual course of action, but according to OP's question, he already tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 10):

Try following: Rigth click -> Team->'share projectS' (plural, in singular does not work) in your disconnected project

I cannot reproduce it now in my PC but there appears a option to reconnect to svn -or to connect using svn information that exists in project-. (Just do as you were going to put a new project in svn, it will see the svn info and will asks you to use it)

I hate that problems....

Comment: I had the same problem as James, and this solution actually worked for me.  I had to do this one project at a time, but this was still faster than saving off my code and doing a clean import.

Answer (score 7):

**Team > Share project** works fine. The disadvantage is SVN supports to share projects **one by one** rather than many projects at a time.

Comment: you can also share multiple projects by selecting them :)

Answer (score 3):

4 years too late, but for anyone who faces this problem :

- If while disconnecting from SVN, the meta-data was erased :

Right click on the project ->

**Team** -> **Share Project** -> **SVN** ->

Use existing repository location -> Next ->

Browse to your project's trunk folder -> OK -> Next ->

Here you will get a commit comment box. Just press Finish ->

A warning sign is displayed in a popup window saying "The project xxx already exists in the repository and has some content. Do you wish to proceed?" ->

Click yes ->

A window will popup showing the progress of prepare commit ->

After completion you will get the actual commit window showing all the resources as modified ->

Click **CANCEL** here ->

It will connect your local project to SVN and also will not commit anything.

Comment: I got a little different warning message and was worried I might lose some changes (made a backup first) but this did work.

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck with the singular version of 'share project'. Had to manually add 'trunk' to the suggested repository path.

Answer (score 0):

After updating Eclipse to 2023-09, I lost connection with my Subversion repositories.
Added Subclipse, didn't help, but could see my SVN repositories in the repository browsing window.

What worked to get back the SVN connection was:
Delete the project from the workspace, but not the files on disk.
Import the project from the disk workspace project directory.
On the project: *Team / Synchronise with Repository*.